# Redis adds "\" to JSON string

Tags: json, redis, backslash

I am using ServiceStack Redis to save a value of a JSON and retrieve it later.
The problem is when i retrieve the value from the redis, it adds multiple "\" and that ruins my JSON.

for example i save:

> { "user": "123456", "password": "xxxxxxx" }

and when i retrieve the value it comes out:

> { \"user\": \"123456\", \"password\": \"xxxxxxx\" }

i was wondering if there is some kind of setting to prevent that? why does it happen?
The JSON contains some "\n" characters that get "\" added to them as well, i just removed them from the example to make it more readable.

Comment: Could you add your code?

Comment: Hi @Cludch after going back to my code to get it here, i noticed that i am cast typeing the result from redis to string (redis returns the value as a byte array) and that is probably why it is adding all those "\", after some testing i will post the official result here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking my code, i noticed that i am type casting to string when returning the data from the Redis (which is returned as a byte array), and it was adding the extra "\".
My solution for the problem was decoding my JSON to a base64String before storing it in the Redis and then decoding it back.

Comment: spent two days on this issue. Storing in bash64 has one drawback as you cannot see through any tool what data you have in cache.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but the code resides in the servers of a company i no longer work for or have access to... /:

Answer (score 0):

The ServiceStack Redis Client serializes complex types as JSON, if you want to store a string as-is then you should only use the [API's that accept a string](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/538555a91eaa4259d76ed72ead5d4ca8e8bff0fa/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/IRedisClient.cs#L80-L92) instead of a generic `T` type, e.g:

```
void SetAll(IEnumerable<string> keys, IEnumerable<string> values);
void SetAll(Dictionary<string, string> map);
void SetValues(Dictionary<string, string> map);

void SetValue(string key, string value);
void SetValue(string key, string value, TimeSpan expireIn);
bool SetValueIfNotExists(string key, string value);
bool SetValueIfExists(string key, string value);

string GetValue(string key);
string GetAndSetValue(string key, string value);

List<string> GetValues(List<string> keys);
```